# how to add opacity to scss variable?

Tags: css, variables, sass, materialize

I am wondering if it is possible to add the opacity element to a sass variable? I am working on a project where I need to create different shades of a color and use them in custom typography file. My problem is when I create a color variable in rdga and implement it into my work the variable changes the code to a CSS opacity element which is written under a color element then this gets ran through the browser and throws and error. Is there a certain way to implement opacity in a variable so you don't get this problem?

Any help would be great, thanks

here are my variables:

```
   $white-text-dh: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
   $white-text-d: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.12);
```

here is the typography ex:

```
  .c-title{
            font-size:20px;
            color: $white-text-d;
            font-family: Roboto-Light;
         }
```

here is the html

```
         <span class="c-title">hello</span>
```

this is what reads in the developer tools with an error going through the color. the color element can not read opacity

```
      .c-title {
                font-size: 20px;
                color: #ffffff opacity 0.7%;
                font-family: Roboto-Light;
                }
```

Comment: Dont know where your problem from. But when i try your code, there is no error. It works fine. See this pen [link](https://codepen.io/duannx/pen/RVOpYy)

Comment: There is no problem with this code. In case you don't know, you can use hex colors in rgba mix, when it sass/scss is compiled it will output rgba color. Some thing like this: $white: rgba(#fff, 0.4); will compile to rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);

Comment: hmm... ok then why is the developer tools showing

Comment: hmm... ok then why is the developer tools showing color:#ffffff opacity 0.7%; when I wrote it in rdga as (255, 255,255, 0.7). when I originally defined the variable? There is something I'm missing. My code shows opacity in the color element, not the rdga format.

Comment: Can you check your code to make sure the variable  $white-text-d is not defined elsewhere?

Comment: no it is defined in one place

Comment: Stupid question, but since you wrote "rdga" three times now, I have to ask. Are you absolutely, positively sure that there are no such errors in your production code?

Comment: The output that you say it is not the default one. It seems that you have a rgba function overwriting the original.

Comment: is there a function overwrite in the css framework materialze? because I know I didn't write that.

Answer (score 9):

I tested this and it works for me:

SCSS

```
$white: #fff;

$white-text-dh: rgba($white, .5);
```

```
.c-title {
     color: $white-text-dh;
}
```

HTML

```
<h1 class="c-title">Test</h1>
```

Comment: No need to even declare the second variable, just use `color:  rgba($white, .5);`